# How do I sign into a gmail account pragmatically without 0Auth2?

Tags: gmail-api

So what I'm trying to do is sign into a Gmail account programmatically and not using 0Auth2 to sign into the user's account. What I'm trying to do is sign into the account I set and then display a link which is in that email's inbox. I've looked a lot and I can't seem to find a way to do this without showing anything or without using 0Auth2. I have installed Google's Gmail API into my Xcode project. Here are some of the places I have looked.

- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios
- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users
- Searching on stackoverflow questions
- other places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create an application that will use special account only to login to gmail, it can't be done without oauth2, but you can take a look at oauth2 scenarios here [google oauth2 scenarios](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

In your case, in my opinion, [server-to-server scenario](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) can be a solution

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to use this without Oauth, and it is stated in the Gmail API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) that all requests to the Gmail API must be authorized by an authenticated user and Gmail uses the [OAuth 2.0 protocol](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) for authenticating a Google account and authorizing access to user data. For more information, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816335).